# Tensorflow error could not find a version that satisfies requirement setup.py

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection-api, nvidia-jetson-nano

I am trying to install `tensorflow` on `jetson nano`. I have followed this [document](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/frameworks/install-tf-jetson-platform/index.html) and have been able to install tensorflow.

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> tf.__version__
>>> '2.5.0'
```

I am now trying to install `object-detection` api. For this I have cloned the repository `https://github.com/tensorflow/models.git` and also installed the proto `sudo apt-get install protobuf-compiler` and ran below commands

```
cd models/research
protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.
cp object_detection/packages/tf2/setup.py .
pip3 install setup.py
```

and getting error in installation of setup.py:

```
Error: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement setup.py (from versions: none)
Error: No matching distribution found for setup.py
```

I am not able to understand why this error is coming. I am using `python3.6` with 64bit version. Can anyone please provide some suggestions on how can I install object detection api for tensorflow

[image]

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: code `pip3 install setup.py`  seems mistake. Maybe it should be `python setup.py` to run code. or `python setup.py install`

Comment: @furas Okay I ran command sudo python3 setup.py install, it started but at then end showed error `No local packages or working download links found for tensorflow_io` , `error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('tensorflow_io')`. Also attached screenshot

Comment: it seems `tensorflow_io` needs at least `Python 3.7` - see [files](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow-io/#files)